# IntelliJ: how to change the color of parameter info popup

Tags: intellij-idea, colors

How do I change the color of this pop up thing. It's incredibly difficult to read.

[image]

Comment: Does the issue occur with the default color scheme? Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Color Scheme | General | Scheme. Did you install any plug-ins that customize it? What file type reproduces the issue? What IDE version do you use? I [can't reproduce it](https://i.imgur.com/mpoTMdo.png).

Comment: @CrazyCoder I came back from the weekend and it had changed to what you have. Not sure why but it works now. Thank you